# Unable to enlarge/resize LUKS partition on virtual disk

Tags: debian, lvm, luks, cryptsetup

I have tried different guides and tutorials to enlarge an encrypted LUKS LVM partition, but I am unable to move forward and finish the process as I don't have complete clarity over the structure of the volumes/partitions. This is a Debian 10 on a VirtualBox VM, I have properly enlarged the virtual disk by approx 10GB, and resized the partition, but when I start the VM and issue `df` I still see the root partition/volume not enlarged. I have performed all the operations with a live `gparted` image, mounting the virtual disk to modify it.

Below is the output of `lsblk` performed from `gparted`:
[image: lsblk output screenshot]

How can I complete the process to enlarge the root volume/partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out the issue.

The procedure I was following was correct, I was just missing one tiny step:

```
pvchange -x y /dev/mapper/encryptedvolume
```

I recommend to follow the instructions in the question #320957 on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, where I found the above step in the second comment of the accepted answer.

Comment: Will accept this as answer in 24h.

Answer (score 1):

Thus far it looks like you have enlarged the virtual disk and the LVM *physical volume*. What you also need to do is enlarge the root LVM *logical volume*:

```
lvextend -r -l +100%FREE GC01VPC-vg/root
```

The command above will increase the size of the root *logical volume* so that it consumes all of the available free space on the `CG01VPC-vg` *volume group*. In addition, the filesystem will be resized as well. In short, the *logical volume* size will increase by about 11GB.